# get a specific value from an xml

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to get a specific value from an xml. When I iterate over the nodes, the value is never returned. Here is the xml sample

```
<Fields>
    <Field FieldName="NUMBER">
      <String>1234</String>
    </Field>
    <Field FieldName="TYPE">
      <String>JAVA</String>
    </Field>
        <Field FieldName="ATYPE">
      <String>BB</String>
    </Field>
</Fields>
```

Here is what I have attempted based on this online resource that looks like my sample xml file

```
private static void updateElementValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("Field");
        Element emp = null;
        //loop for each
        for(int i=0; i<employees.getLength();i++){
            emp = (Element) employees.item(i);
            System.out.println("here is the emp " + emp);
            Node name = emp.getElementsByTagName("NUMBER").item(0).getFirstChild();
            name.setNodeValue(name.getNodeValue().toUpperCase());
        }


    }
```

This is the online resource guiding my attempts

```
https://www.journaldev.com/901/modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser
```

Please assist

Comment: What is your language (API)?

Comment: I am using JAVA

Comment: Are you trying to get a node value or set a node value? You can't just set node value and expect the xml to change. You need to use a [transformer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) to modify a node(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a specific value from XML, XPath API may be more convenient in compare to DOM parser API. Here an example for retrieving value of a "String" elements, which are children of "Field" elements, having attribute "FieldName" with value "NUMBER":

```
// parse XML document from file    
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(fileName));

// prepare an XPath expression
XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("/Fields/Field[@FieldName='NUMBER']/String");

// retrieve from XML nodes using XPath
NodeList list = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

// iterate over resulting nodes and retrieve their values
for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i ++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    // udate node content
    node.setTextContent("New text");
}

// output edited XML document
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); // Use FileWriter to output to the file
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: Updated answer to parse XML from file. But the point is not the source of XML (file, string etc) but the XPath API use, which allows you retrieve node from XML tree with less boilerplate code comparing with DOM API.

Comment: You did not add the node update function after the println statement

Comment: Sure. Updated answer with code fore updating node content and for outputting edited document.